# How to check an object can be used as type annotation in Python?

Tags: python, typing

According to [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#acceptable-type-hints), the following are allowed to be used as type annotation.

```py
v: int # built-in class
v: MyABC # abstract base class
v: types.FunctionType # types defined in `types` module
v: MyClass # user-defined class
v: None # None is a value, but ok
v: typing.List[int] # Generics
```

I want to check if a `variable` can be used as type annotation:

```py
def is_annotation(v: Any) -> bool:
   # How to implement?

is_annotation(int)                == True
is_annotation(1)                  == False
is_annotation(types.FunctionType) == True
is_annotation(None)               == True
```

Comment: There is an internal function _type_check in the typing module that may be a useful roadmap. A very lazy method might be to call this function inside of a try/except block returning true when the function returns since the it is written to raise an exception when there is an invalid type.

Comment: I don't follow.  `None` isn't a variable, and the *implementation* of `is_annotation` doesn't have anything to do with type checking. No matter what logic you have to decide whether to return `True` or `False`, it has zero impact on the question of *whether you are allowed to pass that parameter in the first place*. Furthermore, it's unclear what you expect to happen for, for example, `is_annotation(a - b)`.